# Replace numbers in YAML file with random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, yaml

I have a file with much numbers. I want that every number will be replaced with a random number. So that the Python script changes the YAML file. How to code this in Python?

```
!h 1: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
!h 2: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
!h 3: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
!h 4: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
!h 5: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
!h 6: {X: '-950,00000', Y: '1500,00000', Z: '150,00000'}
```

Comment: The file is  a YAML file (with tags) not an XML file.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me so much! But I have a problem. I have every component installed. I am getting this error. :                                                                  line 53, in <module>
    for v in data.values():
AttributeError: 'CommentedSeq' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `ruamel.yaml`. There are various ways of generating random numbers, since you need them as scalar strings with a comma as decimal separator, I suggest using `random.randrange` and manipulating the result as a string:

```py
import sys
from random import randrange
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

in_file = Path('input.yaml')
out_file = Path('output.yaml')

def randfloatstr():
    # this gives you max 4 digits before the comma and 5 digits after
    x = str(randrange(0, 1000000000))
    return x[:-5] + ',' + x[-5:]
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)
for v in data.values():
    for k in v:
        v[k] = randfloatstr()

yaml.dump(data, out_file)
sys.stdout.write(out_file.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
!h 1: {X: '2767,85747', Y: '8281,59187', Z: '2729,91875'}
!h 2: {X: '324,84623', Y: '6669,00402', Z: '6183,89608'}
!h 3: {X: '5349,15868', Y: '7987,69554', Z: '243,05155'}
!h 4: {X: '6738,35201', Y: '2497,61750', Z: '2933,25689'}
!h 5: {X: '6013,68067', Y: '5265,31446', Z: '9229,21356'}
!h 6: {X: '4656,47702', Y: '4710,97938', Z: '5264,45726'}
```

`ruamel.yaml` will preserve the tags (`!h`), but cannot align the columns for smaller numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this will help me much! But I am getting this error. I have all components installed.                                                                                                                                     `File "randomizer.py", line 53, in <module>
    for v in data.values():
AttributeError: 'CommentedSeq' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: The part following "which gives:" is generated from the code you see and a file **exactly** containing your example YAML. Are you sure your input file is exactly like in your question? Does it have some `[`` or `-`] at the start? I suspect that because your error indicates you loaded a sequence into `data`. In that case you need to do something like `for v in data[0].values():`.

Comment: You can also do `print(data)`  directly after loading, to see what datastructure you loaded.

Comment: Okay, it is loading the file right, but I'm getting this error. I edited the data[0].values() line. I am getting this error: ``for k in v: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable``

Comment: @Anthon: "If that works, accept the answer." - On Stack Overflow we discourage **forcing** anyone to **accept** an answer. If you suspect that an asker new on Stack Overflow and is not aware what "accept" means, then you could *politely* describe that. In other cases there is no reason to remind about accepting an answer.

Comment: @customswitch If the above answer, solves your original problem, please accept the answer (by clicking the V mark to the left of it). That indicates to me and others the problem in your question is solved. Accepting also indicates that  the problems you describe in your comments, and that I so far assume to result from using different input as in your question, can indeed be solved by adapting/extending this answer (instead of coming up with something quite like it, but entirely different).